# C# : MS Chart : SeriesCollection -> InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, mschart, excel-interop, .net

What is the correct way to get the Series of a char in PPT 2010.

I tried

```
PowerPoint.SeriesCollection mySeriesCollection = (PowerPoint.SeriesCollection)
                                                           myChart.SeriesCollection(1);
```

throws the following exception

```
Exception Type:        System.InvalidCastException
```

Further, What is the correct call in C# to get the series of a chart ?

If I try this way:

```
PowerPoint.Series mySeries = (PowerPoint.Series)myChart.SeriesCollection.Item(1);
```

I get the following compile error :

```
error CS0119: 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Chart.SeriesCollection(object)'
is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close; you need to call the `SeriesCollection` method the first way, and cast the second way.

```
PowerPoint.Series mySeries = (PowerPoint.Series)myChart.SeriesCollection(1);
```

Comment: wow, thanks. In fact my code was `Excel.Series mySeries = (Excel.Series)myChart.SeriesCollection(1);`, so in the above example I exchanged Excel with PowerPoint without even trying to run it. With `Excel.Series` I still get the `Exception Type:        System.InvalidCastException`. Could you help me understand why casting to `Excel.Series` is not equal casting to `PowerPoint.Series` ? Don't they use the same `Series` object ?

Comment: The objects they use may be similar, but they're declared in different types (one is declared by Excel, one by PowerPoint) which means they're not interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, could you go deeper into it. Where do the differences come from, i.e. they are not the same object? One shouldnt think in Object Oriented thiking when dealing with MS Office .Net ?!?